# n-th Root Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, nth-root

What is the fastest way to calculate the *n*-th root of a number?

I'm aware of the Try and Fail method, but I need a faster algorithm.

Comment: In C#? `Math.Pow(x, 1.0 / n);` is pretty quick.

Comment: I was trying to do this for Delphi, the function is called Power but the syntax is the same :)

Comment: elegant, simple and efficient @IanHenry. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method). In case you don't know, the derivative of x<sup>n</sup> is nx<sup>n-1</sup>. This will come in handy. 1 is a good first guess. You want to apply it to the function a - x<sup>n</sup>

IIRC, it's superconvergent on functions of the form a - x<sup>n</sup>, but either way, it's quite fast.  Also, IIRC, the warning in the wiki about it failing to converge would apply to more complex functions that have properties that the 'nice' functions you are interested in lack.

Comment: I think he wants the roots of a number, not the roots of an equation.

Comment: @Ian Henry, What's the difference? the real, positive root of a is the real, positive root of the equation a - x^n and vice versa. I did notice that Mitch Wheat posted an already derived version of newtons method that obscures this basic fact.

Comment: Ah, I should've read your whole answer. I had never made that connection. +1 for expanding my (clearly lacking) numerical analysis knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Not the fastest, but it works. Substitute your chosen type:

```
    private static decimal NthRoot(decimal baseValue, int N)
    {
        if (N == 1)
            return baseValue;
        decimal deltaX;
        decimal x = 0.1M;
        do
        {
            deltaX = (baseValue / Pow(x, N - 1) - x) / N;
            x = x + deltaX;
        } while (Math.Abs(deltaX) > 0);
        return x;
    }

    private static decimal Pow(decimal baseValue, int N)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
            baseValue *= baseValue;
        return baseValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the [nth root algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) ? This is not a try-and-fail method, but an iterative algorithm which is repeated until the required precision is reached.