# C# Find Nth Root

Tags: c#, nth-root

I use below method to calculate Nth Root of double value, but it takes a lot of time for calculating the 240th root. I found out about Newton method, but was not able to implement it into a method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
static double NthRoot(double A, int N)
{
   double epsilon = 0.00001d;//
   double n = N;
   double x = A / n;
   while (Math.Abs(A-Power(x,N)) > epsilon)
   {
    x = (1.0d/n) * ((n-1)*x + (A/(Power(x, N-1))));
   }
   return x;
}
```

Comment: did you have a look at this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Pseudocode should no be too difficult to translate into real code

Comment: What actually is the question here? Do you just want it to be faster? Or do you explicitly want to see how the newton method would look in real code?

Comment: I came across POW, but for some reason I though it's same as per the method I posted above. I'm not programmer, and would not have posted  question here unless I was not able to figure it out myself. Thank you

Comment: Where did you get that power-method from? Is it selfwritten or what namespace is it in?

Comment: From here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848640/n-th-root-algorithm , It's funny, I came across Pow but I thought it could not be so simple after learning the method mentioned above. I'm learning (C# by (learn what I need), I try to write indicators for a trading program NinjaTrader.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
static double NthRoot(double A, int N)
{
    return Math.Pow(A, 1.0 / N);
}
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root):

In calculus, roots are treated as special cases of exponentiation, where the exponent is a fraction:

```
\sqrt[n]{x} \,=\, x^{1/n}
```

Comment: But I want the 3th root that use 1.0/3==0.333333333 !=1/3.

Comment: Computer arithmetic is always bound by the precision of the underlying data type. To within enough digits of precision, it's equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same function used to find the power of a number, just use reciprocal of the number instead of the number itself.

To find N root of X you can write,

```
int root = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(X, (1 / N));
```